# I can't seem to figure out how to do a string interpolation; Code Platoon Exercise

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, ecmascript-6

**Self-Guided Teaching myself and stuck on this problem.**

https://www.codeplatoon.org/intro-to-coding-session-3/

```js
// Use string interpolation to refactor this code.

const countdownFive = "There are 5 seconds left until liftoff!"

const countdownFour = "There are 4 seconds left until liftoff!"

const countdownThree = "There are 3 seconds left until liftoff!"

const countdownTwo = "There are 2 seconds left until liftoff!"

const countdownOne = "There is 1 second left until liftoff!"

const liftOff = "Lift Off!"
```

---

**I have tried a few things but nothing has worked. To be completely upfront, I am completely new to programming and literally self-teaching myself everything.**

---

**This is my latest attempt, but I am only getting the last line "Lift Off' to return, I am trying to get it to print out a countdown-type method.**

```js
var five = "5";
var four = "4";
var three = "3";
var two = "2";
var one = "1";

var template5 = `There are ${five} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template4 = `There are ${four} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template3 = `There are ${three} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template2 = `There are ${two} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template1 = `There are ${one} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template = `Lift Off!`

var url = `${template5}`;

var url = `${template4}`;

var url = `${template3}`;

var url = `${template2}`;

var url = `${template1}`;

var url = `${template}`;

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Because your value in `template` override `url`, you need to use different names to hold different string values

Comment: you keep assigning a different value to ```url``` so only the last is counted.


just do ```console.log(`${template1}`);``` ```console.log(`${template}`);``` ...

Comment: What exactly is the objective? Make the code more DRY? "Refactor this code" isn't a very precise description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're constantly reassigning `url` - either log in between:

```js
var five = "5";
var four = "4";
var three = "3";
var two = "2";
var one = "1";

var template5 = `There are ${five} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template4 = `There are ${four} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template3 = `There are ${three} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template2 = `There are ${two} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template1 = `There are ${one} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template = `Lift Off!`

var url = `${template5}`;

console.log(url);

var url = `${template4}`;

console.log(url);

var url = `${template3}`;

console.log(url);

var url = `${template2}`;

console.log(url);

var url = `${template1}`;

console.log(url);

var url = `${template}`;

console.log(url);
```

Or use `join` (this will print in one statement on multiple lines):

```js
var five = "5";
var four = "4";
var three = "3";
var two = "2";
var one = "1";

var template5 = `There are ${five} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template4 = `There are ${four} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template3 = `There are ${three} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template2 = `There are ${two} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template1 = `There are ${one} seconds left until liftoff!`

var template = `Lift Off!`

var url = [template5, template4, template3, template2, template1, template].join("\n");

console.log(url);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I will take a closer look into how to use joins better.